# Read Json file and extract Values php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

I need you're help, I want to extract every value from a json array stored in file.
for exemple : get the tel_fixe value only : My code is =>

```
...
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT tel_fixe,tel_mobile FROM lead");
$table=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $table[] = $row;
}
file_put_contents("json_mysql/json".$date_test.".txt", json_encode($table));

$dossier_injection = 'inject_json/';
$dossier_backup = 'backup_json/';

$filenames = 'json'.$date_test.'.txt';
$filename = $dossier_injection.'json'.$date_test.'.txt';

$str = file_get_contents($filename);
$json = json_decode($str, true);

mysqli_query($conn,"insert into json_injection (nom_fichier, date_injection) values ('$filename','$date_test')");

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        if ($val <> 0 ) {
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into result (tel_fixe,tel_mobile) value (????, ??????)");
        }
    }
}
rename($filename, 'backup_json/OK'.$filenames);
```

OUTPUT==>

The code below Output

```
[{"tel_fixe":"xxxxxxxxxx","tel_mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"},
{"tel_f‌​ixe":"xxxxxxxxxx","t‌​el_mobile":"xxxxxxxx‌​xx"},
{"tel_fixe":"xx‌​xxxxxxxx","tel_mobil‌​e":"xxxxxxxxxx"},
{"t‌​el_fixe":"xxxxxxxxxx‌​","tel_mobile":"xxxx‌​xxxxxx"},
{"tel_fixe"‌​:"xxxxxxxxxx","tel_m‌​obile":"xxxxxxxxxx"}‌​,
{"tel_fixe":"xxxxxx‌​xxxx","tel_mobile":"‌​xxxxxxxxxx"},.....]
```

Thanks :) (y)

Comment: instead of commenting edit your question with output

Comment: Like this Mr SIDDIQUI?